# ORA-02291 error. Unsure what is causing the problem

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

Everything runs fine. End part gives an `ORA-02291` error. Not sure what would be causing that error, since I thought all the code was running well. This was made in Oracle SQL developer, the error message is ORA-02291. I hope someone can give me an answer. Please help me.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE comm_customer
( 
Customer_Id int NOT NULL,
Customer_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Billing_Address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
phone INT NOT NULL,
primary key(Customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comm_orders
(
order_Id INT NOT NULL,
Customer_id INT NOT NULL,
order_date DATE NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
Order_status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
primary key(order_id),
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id ) REFERENCES comm_customer(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comm_products
( 
product_id INT NOT NULL, 
product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
product_price decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
product_quantity decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
product_status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
customer_id int NOT NULL, 
primary key(product_id),
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id ) REFERENCES comm_customer(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comm_shipments
(
shipment_id INT NOT NULL,
order_id INT NOT NULL,
shipment_date DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (shipment_id),
FOREIGN KEY (order_id ) REFERENCES  comm_orders(order_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comm_shopping_cart
( 
orderdetails_id INT NOT NULL,
order_id INT NOT NULL,
product_id int NOT NULL,
quantity int NOT NULL,
price decimal(5,2),
primary key(orderdetails_id),
FOREIGN KEY (order_id ) REFERENCES comm_orders(order_id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id ) REFERENCES comm_products(product_id)

);

--For Table Comm_customer
insert into comm_customer values(1011, 'John', '48 Maple Heights Road', '48 Maple Heights Road', 'Toronto', 'Canada', 9988766779);
insert into comm_customer values(1012, 'James', '32 St.Jordan Cressent', '32 St.Jordan Cressent', 'Chennai', 'India', 9988722779);
insert into comm_customer values(1013, 'Anderson', '5 Thornway Street', '#1755 JBS Colony', 'Surat', 'India', 9988123779 );
insert into comm_customer values(1014, 'Jose', '88 Greenbelt Drive', '#1983 ABS Nagar', 'Mumbai', 'India', 9988766885 );
insert into comm_customer values(1015, 'Leo', '#1765 XSX Nagar', '#10993 ACD Nagar', 'Hoshiarpur', 'India', 9955466779 );

--For Table Comm_products:
INSERT into comm_products values(01, 'XI Phone', 250, 4, 'checked out', 1015);
INSERT into comm_products values(02, 'Book', 120, 2, 'not checked out', 1011); 
INSERT INTO comm_products values(03, 'Vegetable',100, 5, 'not checked out', 1012); 
INSERT into comm_products values(04, 'Biscuits', 250, 1, 'checked out', 1013);
INSERT into comm_products values(05, 'Shampoo', 500, 2, 'not checked out', 1014); 

--For table Comm_orders:
insert into comm_orders values(11, 1014, '2020-MAY-01', 500, 'checked out'); 
insert into comm_orders values(12, 1011, '2019-JUL-18', 140, 'not checked out');
insert into comm_orders values(13, 1013, '2020-JAN-31', 170, 'checked out'); 
insert into comm_orders values(14, 1012, '2019-FEB-15', 120, ' not checked out');
insert into comm_orders values(15, 1011, '2018-JUN-21', 600, 'checked out');


--For table comm_shippments:
insert into comm_shipments values(001, 13, '2020-FEB-05');
insert into comm_shipments values(002, 15, '2018-JUL-01');
insert into comm_shipments values(003, 12, '2019-07-25'); 
insert into comm_shipments values(004, 11, '2020-MAY-05');
insert into comm_shipments values(005, 14, '2019-FEB-25'); 

--For table comm_shopping_cart:
insert into comm_shopping_cart values(701, 01, 11, 4, 250);
insert into comm_shopping_cart values(702, 02, 12, 3, 120);
insert into comm_shopping_cart values(704, 03, 13, 6, 100);
insert into comm_shopping_cart values(703, 04, 14, 2, 250);
insert into comm_shopping_cart values(705, 05, 15, 1, 500);
```

Comment: You're getting an integrity constraint error so presumably one of the `insert` statements is failing.  It would be helpful to tell us which statement is failing for you.

Comment: its the first one for comm_shopping_cart

Comment: @Laser - FYI, If you reply to someone without typing "@TheirUsername" in the reply, they won't get a notification and won't know that you've answered the question they asked unless they happen to come back to the question later.

Comment: [ORA-02291 integrity constraint (string.string) violated - parent key not found](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e2100.htm#1004903): **Cause**: *A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.* **Action**: *Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.* What is not clear here?

Comment: Some side observations on your data model, unrelated to your error:  First, you should be using VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR, which is only supported for backward compatibility.  Second, it's simply lazy to define all of your VARCHAR columns with length of 255.  While a varchar or varchar2 with only two bytes of actual data will take only two bytes of _storage_, when memory is allocated to work with it, it will still be allocated 255 bytes, potentially leading to insufficient memory.  (cont ...)

Comment: (.... cont). Third, telephone numbers are not numbers, they are character strings that only use numeric characters. By defining it as a NUMBER (or INT, which is a type of NUMBER), you will lose any potential leading zeros.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so you say the statement that is erroring out is this

```
insert into comm_shopping_cart values(701, 01, 11, 4, 250);
```

I'd strongly urge you to list the columns in your `insert` statement.  That helps to document things so that someone doesn't have to constantly refer up to the table definition to see what order columns are defined in.  And it means that your statements won't suddently fail in the future when you add new columns.

```
insert into comm_shopping_cart( orderdetails_id,
                                order_id,
                                product_id,
                                quantity,
                                price) 
  values(701, 
          01, 
          11, 
           4, 
         250);
```

OK, so having done that, the error is that the parent key isn't found.  Your actual error message should include the name of the constraint which would tell you which column is the problem.  You haven't given us that information so we'll have to figure it out.  There are two foreign keys on `comm_shopping_cart`, the `order_id` and the `product_id`.  So which one doesn't exist?

You're trying to insert a row with an `order_id` of 01 (I don't understand why you're putting leading 0's in a numeric column).  But you only have `order_id` values in the `comm_orders` table between 11 and 15.

You're also trying to insert a row with a `product_id` of 11.  But you only have `product_id` values between 1 and 5 in your `comm_products` table.  So both foreign key constraints would fail.

My guess is that you intended to specify an `order_id` of 11 and a `product_id` of 1 in your `insert` statement and reversed the order of the columns.  Since you didn't include the column list in your `insert` statement, you made it much harder on yourself to debug the problem because your `insert` statements aren't self-documenting.  Had you specified the column list, you could also have listed the columns in whatever order you wanted so if you wanted to specify the `product_id` before the `order_id` you could have.